# How to install ".vsix" file to use the extension

Tags: visual-studio

I am trying to install `AutoSaveFile.vsix` file downloaded from the following site to add the auto save function.

[Auto Save File](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=HRai.AutoSaveFile)

I have tried it by referring to the installation method on the following site, but it does not work...

[Manage extensions for Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/finding-and-using-visual-studio-extensions?view=vs-2019)

a method introduced first (Manage Extensions dialog box) does not work, so I am trying the method introduced second(Install without using the Manage Extensions dialog box).

Select the target（`AutoSaveFile.vsix`） file by the following method, but even if I double-click or press ENTER, the file is not selected and I cannot install it.

[Visual Studi] -> [Extension] -> [Install from file]　-> [All files] -> select the target file

Does anyone know how to solve this problem？

---

Visual Studio for Mac Community 8.10.7

Mac Big Sur 11.5.2

Comment: 1. Check that you have VS installed, 2. Check the file extension actually is .vsix and you don't have the real file extension hidden e.g. myfile.vsix.txt with hidden extensions looks like myfile.vsix. 3. Try re-downloading extension. 4. Try re-installing VS.

Comment: @ Danny Varod, Thank you for your information, I tried your method but it doesn't work.

Comment: Extensions for Visual Studio for Windows won't work for VS for Mac.